# Datasheet VN2222

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

I couldn't find the datasheet for VN2222 I need it to find Vt, Cox, W, L to evaluate the current ID. All I found is VN2222l which is not what I want, or do they have the same characteristics?
[image]

Comment: No datasheet is going to tell you W and L; you're using a MOSFET model designed for IC design.

Comment: Discrete devices are bulk produced devices whereas the devices used for IC designs are built in fabs using photomasks. W/L applies to IC design and not to discrete devices.